# Message: Missing argument 2 for ::__construct(),

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a codeigniter constructor that begins like:

```
public function __construct($login, $pass)
```

I'm trying to pass parameters to it in my controller like so:

```
 $params = array(1=>'xxx',2 =>'yyy');
 $this->load->library('my_library',$params);
```

but I'm getting:

```
Message: Missing argument 2 for my_library::__construct(),
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CI doesn't work that way. The constructor should accept a single parameter like

```
public function __construct($param)
{
    // access $param['login'] and $param['pass']
}
```

and invoke it like

```
$this->load->library('my_library', array(
    'login' => 'xxx',
    'pass' => 'yyy',
));
```

which is an array of your data

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html